# MediaElement XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I am trying to use the "AreTransportControlsEnabled=true" property of an MediaElement in order to get controls buttons.

I read that it was available on the windows phone 8.1 
According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aretransportcontrolsenabled.ASPx)

My project is for

> Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

I added this snippets of code to the MainPage.xaml:

```
<DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid x:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground" Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded">
    <MediaElement
        x:Name="VideoPlayer" 
        Source="test.mp4"  
        AutoPlay="False" 
        MediaEnded="OnMediaEnded" 
        Stretch="Fill"             
    />
</DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid>
```

The problem is that when I add 'AreTransportControlsEnabled="true"'

```
<DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid x:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground" Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded">
    <MediaElement
        x:Name="VideoPlayer" 
        Source="test.mp4"  
        AutoPlay="False" 
        MediaEnded="OnMediaEnded" 
        Stretch="Fill"    
        AreTransportControlsEnabled=true         
    />
</DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid>
```

AreTransportControlsEnabled isn't recognized or accessible and I can't build the application.
I can't find the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I found out that I was using System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement which doesn't have a AreTransportControlsEnabled property unlike Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement. The problem remains the same since Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement isn't available and I can't find the reference that I need to add to the project. Where can I find such information?

Comment: Ok just found that Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement is available for Windows Phone 8.1 and not for Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 : [source](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/Media/DiffLists/Windows%20Phone%208.1%20%28Silverlight%29-vs-Windows%20Phone%208.1.html) I must change the type of my project.